# Android app disconnect from RabbitMQ after using activity method

Tags: android, kotlin, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement RabbitMQ into my android App, but having an issue that inside the `handleDelivery` method when i am trying to call an outer function the connection getting lost.

```
private fun initRabbitmq () {
    factory.setUri("someURI")
    subscribeThread = Thread(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val connection: Connection = factory.newConnection()
            val channel: Channel = connection.createChannel()
            val consumer: DefaultConsumer
            consumer = object : DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                override fun handleDelivery(consumerTag: String?, envelope: Envelope?, properties: AMQP.BasicProperties?, body: ByteArray?) {
                    super.handleDelivery(consumerTag, envelope, properties, body)
                    val msg = String(body!!, Charsets.UTF_8)
                    Log.e(TAG, "RabbitMQ - $msg")
                    showRabbitMessage(msg)
                }
            }
            channel.basicConsume("defenders_test", true, consumer)
        }
    })
    subscribeThread.start()
}
```

When the function `showRabbitMessage()` being executed the connection being lost, but if i am removing it and watching the logs, the messages being displayed in the console.

Any idea how to get the message out of the Thread?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i had to transfer the object from the thread -> out, and in android it can be done by using the `Handle` object and `handleMessage()` method.